# How to dynamically connect and disconnect stdin in child_process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, quake

I'm attempting to spawn a Quake server through node's `child_process`. According to the `child_process`, using the `'ignore'` string for the `stdin` index *should* ignore the input, yet it's still locking my input to the launched console application.

```
const path = require('path');

const cp = require('child_process');
const myPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'quake1', 'fteqwsv64.exe');
//Launch the Quake1 server, direct the output to node's process output. Don't take input.
let quake = cp.spawn(myPath, {
    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit']
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. It locks my input to the console to the launched application.

How can I properly control stdio's input?